# Unable to append to a list

Tags: python

Background:
I've a text files that has inputs like:

```
#1 GLN 15.A OE1
#1 ILE 16.A C
#1 ILE 16.A CA
#1 ILE 16.A CB
#1 ILE 16.A CD1
```

I convert this file into a string in python. And I get the outputs (say numbers) I want to.

A part of the code is here:

```
def extractnum(s):
   x = s.split('\n')
   x.pop() #To remove last line which is empty
   y = [ i.split() for i in x ]
   z = [ j[2] for j in y ] #z is the list that contains the residue and chain information
   n = [int(k.split('.')[0]) for k in z]
   a_chain_residues = ''
   ca_a_chain_residues = ''
   list_of_a_chain_residues = [ ]
   for i in list(set(z)): #list(set(z)) gives a list that removes all the duplicate items in z: it doesn't change z
      if i[-1] == 'A':
          a_chain_residues = a_chain_residues + i +','
          ca_a_chain_residues = ca_a_chain_residues + i + '.ca,'
          list_of_a_chain_residues = list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
      print list_of_a_chain_residues
```

The error in terminal reads

```
extractnum(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 17, in extractnum
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why can't 'i' add to a list? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that:

```
>>>i = []
>>>print i.append(2)
None
```

The returned values of this append is `None`.

So, When doing this:

```
list_of_a_chain_residues = list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```

You set `list_of_a_chain_residues` to be `None`, because append does not return a value.
Do this instead:

```
list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

`append` does not return a value; it modifies the list directly.  You will get the desired effect by simply typing:

```
list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with append to list which returns None, if you do so you'll get answer

```
def extractnum(s):
    x = s.readlines()
    x.pop() #To remove last line which is empty
    y = [ i.split() for i in x ]
    z = [ j[2] for j in y ] #z is the list that contains the residue and chain information
    n = [int(k.split('.')[0]) for k in z]
    a_chain_residues = ''
    ca_a_chain_residues = ''
    list_of_a_chain_residues = [ ]
    for i in list(set(z)): #list(set(z)) gives a list that removes all the duplicate items in z: it doesn't change z
        if i[-1] == 'A':
            a_chain_residues = a_chain_residues + i +','
            ca_a_chain_residues = ca_a_chain_residues + i + '.ca,'
            list_of_a_chain_residues = list_of_a_chain_residues + list(i)
        print list_of_a_chain_residues

s = open("./file1.txt",'r')
extractnum(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type for `append` method in `python list` is always `None`. append() works in-place i.e. it modifies the original list then and there.

```
list_of_a_chain_residues = list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```

In the above line, no doubt, the value in `i` is being appended to the list `list_of_a_chain_residues`, but in the next moment, immediately you are assigning the return value of `append` to `list_of_a_chain_residues` (which is `None`). So, even though the list is getting appended, assigning itself to the return value of `append()` loses all the progress and makes it `None`.
Therefore, replace the line

```
list_of_a_chain_residues = list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```

simply by

```
list_of_a_chain_residues.append(i)
```